# How can I create a text file that saves an entry from tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, class, tkinter, text

This is my current `db.py` file, it contains the tkinter code for creating the GUI:

```py
import tkinter
import db

app = Tk()
app.geometry("450x300")

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can get answer to your question by reading available documentation. It's not clear why you need our help. Probably every python tutorial out there shows how to create files, and getting data out of an entry widget is also very well documented.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `Entry` widget with a linked variable to get the input from user. The content can then be retrieved from the variable and written to a file using [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

I like to use themed-tkinter(`ttk`). If you just starting with creating GUI, I suggest you read more about *themed-tkinter*  [here](https://tkdocs.com/).

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# StringVar has all the logic to store and update string values
content = tk.StringVar()

def callback():
    # This function is invoked when button `submit` is clicked
    with open('content.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(content.get())

entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=content).grid()
submit = ttk.Button(root, text='submit', command=callback).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**: I worded my answer wrongly for which I appologize. Tkinter by itself is indeed robust and powerful. I found it more easier to use `ttk` in many cases and had a softcorner towards it.

Comment: I don't think that first statement is at all true. tkinter itself is exceptionally robust, and I would argue more robust than ttk. Besides, whether ttk or tkinter, it has no bearing on the question being asked.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I should have been more careful with my words. I love and use tk a lot myself. Instead of painting a good picture on ttk, I threw rotton tomatos at tk. I have edited my answer. Thanks for the critic.